# Подключение к Linux MySQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linux

У меня есть **Linux Server**, на нем поднят **MySQL Server**.

Мой вопрос вот в чем: как осуществить подключение из **`Win7`** к **`Linux MySQL Server`**, по интернету?

Искал в интернете, такого не находил. Было подключение к серверу не виртуальной машине, но там **`Win`** and **`Win`**.

```
        SqlConnection SQL = new SqlConnection();
        SQL = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.101/phpmyadmin; Integrated Security =SSPI; Initial Catalog=Read;");
        SQL.Open();
```

Объясните дураку.

Comment: И плюс к этому как мне правильно поставить запросы в обращение к базе, а выполняется эта работа на C#.

Comment: Вы бы уточнили, какой именно SQL-сервер, а? а то тут под `SQL Server` все понимают `Microsoft SQL`... с другой стороны у Вас по тексту в коде светится `phpmyadmin`, который, к слову сказать, вообще не SQL-сервер, а пакет PHP-скриптов для управления сервером `MySQL` (и соответственно источником данных он ну никак быть не может)...

Comment: Ну на Linux Стоит phpmyadmin, через него была создана MySql база.

Comment: То есть у Вас MySQL-сервер? ну тогда проверьте, что им используется стандартный порт (3306), что разрешены внешние подключения (слушается локальный адрес), создайте пользователя, имеющего право подключения извне - и подключайтесь. Для начала - штатным клиентом командной строки или штатным же WorkBench (оба ставятся на Win7 из штатного инсталлятора Community-сервера).

Comment: Ну это хорошо, в моем случае я делаю программу для чтения базы. Заказчик требует что в выпадающем списке отображалась база и сразу же подключение к нему.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html